# Access of Outlook mail using powershell script

Tags: powershell, outlook

I am trying to access the Outlook mail to manage it through powershell script and it works fine but when script tries to access the content of mail,outlook is asking for permission to allow access to script.Is there any way so that I can allow only my script to access the Outlook mail content.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you get a standard security prompt in Outlook when accessing some sensitivity properties from the Outlook object model.

There are several ways for suppressing such prompts:

1. Use a third-party components for supressing Outlook security warnings. See [Security Manager for Microsoft Outlook](https://www.add-in-express.com/outlook-security/index.php) for more information.
2. Use a low-level API instead of OOM. Or any other third-party wrappers around that API, for example, Redemption.
3. Develop a COM add-in that has access to the trusted `Application` object. And then communicate from a standalone application with an add-in using standard .Net tools (Remoting).
4. Use group policy objects for setting up machines.